# Error: Unexpected field when doing multer image upload

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer

I am trying to test out my routes using postman. However I am making a request and I get the error Error: Unexpected field. I am not sure why I am getting this error.  Here's my code for the post req. Would it help if I put image:req.file in my new listing variable? Help is appreciated.

```
router.post(
  "/",
  passport.authenticate("jwt",  {
    session: false
  }),upload.single("productImage"),
  (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file);
    const { errors, isValid } = validateListingInput(req.body);
    // if (!isValid) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
     }
    const newListing = new Listing({
      username: req.body.username,
      user: req.user.id,
      price: req.body.price,
      size: req.body.size
    });
    newListing.save().then(post => res.json(post));
  }
);
```

Comment: Is "productImage" declared as "productImage" in your `input file` html?

Comment: @James I am not sure what you mean by input file html. I am using MongoDB, are you talking about the mongoose schema?

Comment: What does your request look like in Postman?

Comment: Before thinking about MongoDB and Multer, you need to update your references in front-end (`input type="file"`) to reach Multer reference (`upload.single`). your `upload.single("productImage")` needs to match with your `input` name.